# Can’t install Windows Media player 10, getting ‘a more recent version of windows media player is already running on your computer setup cannot continue’

Tags: windows-xp, windows-media-player, sp3

Seems like WMP11 comes with SP3. That means WMP10 is never installed on this XP SP3 OS. Is there any way to downgrade it back to WMP10? Thanks!

EDIT:
I am getting this error message no matter when trying to install WMP10. I've tried to reinstall/uninstall WMP11 but still can't fix this. Is there any place in registry that can fix this? I suspect this is not directly related to WMP registry but some dependency stuff like DRM. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by deleting all "wmvcore.dll" and "wmploc.dll" libraries in system drive. ref: [how to remove DRM](http://undrm.info/faq/removing-DRM/faq-how-to-remove-DRM-from-Windows-Media-Player-files-with-fu4wm13fix-1-milOtis.htm). Looks like WMP installer find cached wmcore and wmploc libraries even delete them in system32 folder. Which is making downgrade WMP so painful!

Answer (score 1):

**[How to uninstall Windows Media Player 11 in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934372)**

In case you'll have to install WMP 10, you can download the full installer at **[filehippo.com](http://www.filehippo.com/download_windows_media_player/119/)**

> Seems like WMP11 comes with SP3

I don't think so ... I'm running SP3 with WMP9.

[image]

However, WMP 11 is distributed via Automatic Update, so you may have to change your Windows Update settings, or WMP 11 will be back in no time. :)

Comment: Thanks. But my WMP was installed through "Control Panel > Add remove programs > add remove windows components wizard > (by checking) Windows Media Player". So I can't either see %windir%\$ntUninstallwmp11$ or 'WMP' entry in add remove programs.

How should I do with this?

Comment: @Stan - did you check box saying "Show updates" in add or remove programs?

Comment: Yes! What I've done so far. 1.uncheck WMP from 'add remove windows components wizard', 2.delete C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player folder, 3.delete C:\WINDOWS\system32\wmp*, 4.Delete the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Setup\Installed from registry.

But I am still getting 'a more recent version of windows media player is already running on your computer setup cannot continue'

Comment: @Stan - you did what?? Not really a surprise then, that the proper uninstallation method doesn't work ... is WMP listed under the following reg key? HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SOFTWARE \MicrosoftWindows\ Current Version \Uninstall ... no, DO NOT delete this key.

Comment: I checked 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SOFTWARE \MicrosoftWindows\ Current Version \Uninstall' but found no WMP entry. I know it's about add remove programs list. But it wasn't there since beginning. :)

Comment: By now, your best bet is probably to reinstall WMP 11 properly and then uninstall it ... what a mess. and while we're at it: got any particular reason to get rid of WMP 11?

Comment: Need to use fairuse4wm. reinstalling WMP11 now. :)

Comment: Still getting 'a more recent version of windows media player is already running on your computer setup cannot continue' after reinstall/uninstall.

Comment: According to its home page, fairuse4wm supports WMP 11.